# Synchronization not working when static wrapper class object is used. Why?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to print even and odd numbers using two different threads.

The code is given below :

```
public class OddEvenThread extends Thread{
    static Integer counter = 2;
    static Object lock = new Object();
    int max = 20;
    public void printEven() throws InterruptedException{

        synchronized(counter){
            while(counter < (max-1)){
            while(counter % 2 != 0){
                System.out.println("Even thread Waiting");
                counter.wait();
                System.out.println("notified");
            }
            System.out.println("Even thread printing: "+ counter);
            counter++;
            System.out.println("Notifying odd thread"+counter);
            counter.notify();
        }
        }
    }

    public void printOdd() throws InterruptedException{

        synchronized(counter){
            while(counter < (max-1)){
            while(counter % 2 == 0){
                System.out.println("Odd thread Waiting");
                counter.wait();
                System.out.println("notified");
            }
            System.out.println("Odd thread printing: "+ counter);
            counter++;
            System.out.println("Notifying even thread"+ counter);
            counter.notify();
        }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        OddEvenThread t1 = new OddEvenThread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    printEven();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        OddEvenThread t2 = new OddEvenThread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    printOdd();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println("Complete");

    }
}
```

This code fails with different outputs. Sometimes it prints "Complete", sometimes not.

A sample output is:

```
Odd thread printing: 1
Notifying even thread2
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at com.customthreadpool.OddEvenThread.printOdd(OddEvenThread.java:34)
    at com.customthreadpool.OddEvenThread$2.run(OddEvenThread.java:53)
```

If different static lock (ref line 3) is used, then code works fine. In that case synchronization block looks like:

```
synchronized(lock){
            while(counter < (max-1)){
            while(counter % 2 != 0){
                System.out.println("Even thread Waiting");
                lock.wait();
                System.out.println("notified");
            }
            System.out.println("Even thread printing: "+ counter);
            counter++;
            System.out.println("Notifying odd thread"+counter);
            lock.notify();
        }
        }
```

What I'm missing in this code ?

Comment: Every time you use an object as a lock, make sure it's declared as final, because the lock should never change. Once you do that, you'll see where the problem is. Using an Integer as a lock is a terrible idea in general. Especially a pooled one like 2.

Comment: Just to say that explicit: `synchronized` operates on *objects*, not variables. Using the same variable for `synchronized` doesn’t help when it can point to different objects.